# Weep holes no longer even exist on the outside

Tags: windows

My sliding glass window sills fill up with water and spill over onto the inside of the house, because the weep holes are literally framed in on the outside of the house. (You can see the holes on the inside of the window sill, and then they are not present on the outside of the house to drain it- I guess someone who put those windows in just put in the wrong type of frame, or who knows) Is there a product or special standardized flashing that I can fill the windowsill with (from glass to outside frame or sill)that could Prevent the sills from being filled with water?  If not- is my only chance to replace all the windows? This is a 16 window waterfront home that sees lots of hurricanes and rain and wind.

Comment: Please post photos